# Removing -Path item from Get-ChildItem Cmdlet in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

How to remove path when I type `ls` in PowerShell. I would like formatting of other items to stay the same, (`Mode`, `LastWriteTime`, `Length`, `Name`). Just to remove line `Directory C:\`. I have been playing around and I'm able to remove it, but then can't get formatting of other items right.

Comment: Giving you a solution will be much easier if you can explain **why** you feel the need to do this.

Comment: Mostly commenting if someone else comes here. How does `ls | select mode,lastwritetime,length,name` not give you the results you desire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formatting you see on the screen is determined by the [Format.ps1xml](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847831.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) file.

The format changes when you use `Select-Object` and select specific properties because you've change the object type (if you do a `get-type()` you'll see it's now a `PSSelectedObject` or `PSCustomObject`), and that formatting is no longer applied.

I think the easiest way to get what you're after may be to override the Format.ps1xml file with a new entry that doesn't display the directory name.